# Is this theory of well founded countable sets formalized in infinitary logic, complete and categorical?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, infinitary-logic

Working in [$\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega_1}$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/), add symbol $=$ with its axioms; add symbol $\in$ and axiomatize:

$\textbf{Extensionality: } \forall x \forall y : \forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$

$\textbf{Foundation: }  (\forall v_n)_{n \in \omega} \, \exists x: \bigvee_{n \in \omega} (x=v_n) \land \bigwedge_{n \in \omega} (v_n \not \in x)$

$\textbf{Define: } x=\{y \mid \phi\} \equiv_{def} \forall y \, (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi)$

$\textbf{Construction: } \\(\forall v_n)_{n \in \omega} \, \exists x : x=\{y \mid    \bigvee_{n \in \omega} ( y=v_n)\}$

$ \textbf{Countability: } \\ \forall x \,  (\exists v_n)_{n \in \omega}  : x=\{y \mid y \neq v_0 \land    \bigvee_{n \in \omega} ( y=v_n)\} $

$\textbf {Empty set: } \exists x \forall y: y \not \in x$.

> Is this theory Complete?

> Is this theory Categorical?

Comment: What do you mean by the "Define" axiom? Is it merely the empty set axiom, or something else?

Comment: @YairHayut It’s not an axiom at all, but a definition of comprehension terms as a shorthand notation. It just explains what “$x=\{y\mid\dots\}$” means in the next two axioms.

Comment: @YairHayut, Yes! I think you are right. I need to add an axiom against this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is categorical and hence complete (with respect to any satisfactory notion of proof, that is). Specifically, I claim that any model $M$ of your theory is isomorphic to $\mathsf{HC}$, the set of hereditarily countable sets.

First, given $M$ we can construct recursively an embedding $i:\mathsf{HC}\rightarrow M$. (Note that this uses the "construction" axiom.) So we just need to show that $i$ is surjective. I think the cleanest way to do this is to note that the image of $i$ is $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$-definable in $M$, as "$a\in im(i)$ iff there is a well-founded countably-branching tree such that, when we recursively label the nodes of $T$ by the sets of labels of their children, the root gets labelled with $a$." (In fact, since $M$ correctly computes well-foundedness and countability this is a first-order definition in $M$, but that doesn't matter.) Now every element of $M\setminus im(i)$ must consist only of elements of $M\setminus im(i)$, but this contradicts well-foundedness.

Note that the ability to characterize well-foudnedness makes $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$ diverge wildly from the standard model-theoretic constraints we are used to for first-order logic or even $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$. That said, the situation shouldn't be overstated: see [S. Friedman's *Model theory for $\mathcal{L}_{\infty\omega_1}$*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007284900125) for a discussion of what sort of "local" compactness phenomena (analogous to Barwise compactness) can still occur.

Comment: One very minor caveat: This theory also admits the empty model (since all its axioms are universals), unless you set up your logic to preclude the empty model entirely.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, yes the underlying logic does presume the existence of at least one object.

Comment: there is a problem about the $\sf HC$ since its cardinality is not determined in $\sf ZF$? So if all models are isomorphic then what is their cardinality? Is it $\omega_1$?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar That doesn't affect this answer. Different models of $\mathsf{ZF(C)}$ disagree about the properties of $\mathsf{HC}$. However, this doesn't affect the fact that $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves "Every model of your theory is isomorphic to $\mathsf{HC}$." Think by analogy about how different models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ disagree over the properties of the real numbers, but the second-order theory of the reals is still $\mathsf{ZF}$-provably categorical.